# MS Access SQL Query to find overlapping subgroupings or subsets

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables showing the components of major roles and minor roles. Major roles are known to "contain" minor roles (the components are the same), but they aren't defined that way.

EDIT: Some minor roles are partially, but not wholly, represented in major roles. I only want to see the minor roles where there is a total match of all components. MiRoleY below, is an example of this. Query should ignore these, and return the bare components

Example:

Table 1: Major Roles

```
MajorRoleName  Component
MaRoleA         ENTM1
MaRoleA         ENTM2
MaRoleA         ENTM3
MaRoleA         ENTM4
MaRoleA         ENTM5 
MaRoleA         ENTM6
MaRoleA         ENTM7
```

Table 2 Minor Roles

```
MinorRoleName   Component
MiRoleZ          ENTM1
MiRoleZ          ENTM2
MiRoleX          ENTM3
MiRoleX          ENTM4
MiRoleY          ENTM5
MiRoleY          ENTM6
MiRoleY          ENTM8
```

What I want to do is redefine the Major Roles so I end up with:

```
MajorRoleName Component
MaRoleA         MiRoleZ    
MaRoleA         MiRoleX
MaRoleA         ENTM5
MaRoleA         ENTM6
MaRoleA         ENTM7
```

I don't need to actually update the database, at this point I only want to read the data (get the definition of major roles in terms of the minor roles they contain)

Is there a way to write a query that will show this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you want?

```
select distinct majorrolename, minorrolename
from majorroles join
     minorroles
     on majorroles.component = minorroles.component;
```

Comment: throws a syntax error "Syntax error in the FROM clause"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct 
    majorrolename, 
    nz(minorrolename, majorroles.component) as component
from 
    majorroles 
left join (
  select * from minorroles as m1 
  where not exists (
    select * from MinorRoles m2 
    where m2.MinorRoleName = m1.MinorRoleName 
      and m2.Component not in (select Component from MajorRoles)
  ) 
) a on majorroles.component = a.component
order by 2 desc;
```

this gives you a result like:

```
majorrolename   component
MaRoleA         MiRoleZ
MaRoleA         MiRoleX
MaRoleA         ENTM7
MaRoleA         ENTM6
MaRoleA         ENTM5
```

(Tested w/ Access 2010)

Comment: This worked perfectly with the sample data i provided but did not do what i expected when i ran it with real data. There is another level of complexity in the real data which is (for example) a minor role with 3 components, and only 2/3 of them are in the major role. i would not expect this minor role name to appear. i am updating the the OP to show what i mean

Comment: @RLWFNM Ok, sure, will look at it.